# How can I customize the 'home' and 'end' key navigation on ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I've customized the arrow navigation keys using the callback 'navigateToNextCell'.

But now I want to customize '**Home**' and '**End**' key.

There is any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not super easy at the moment... here are some relevant "enhancements" that have been requested on the github page:

[support page up/ down, home and end keys](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/452)

[allow overriding of keyboard events](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/180)

[Suggestion: Allow any key for navigation (not just tab)](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1288)

That last link has something useful. There is a comment on how to disable any propagation of the 'home' and 'end' keys:

```
// note, this is angular 2 code, `this.el.nativeElement` is just the grid component
document.documentElement.addEventListener(
  'keydown',
  (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    // this runs on the document element, so check that we're in the grid
    if (this.el.nativeElement.contains(e.target)) {
      if (e.key === 'Tab' || e.key === 'Home' || e.key === 'End') {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      if (e.key === 'Home' || e.key === 'End') {
        // we don't want to prevent the default tab behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  },
  true
);
```

AFTER you have done that, you could add new event listeners to the grid, or depending on what you are trying to do, you could add listeners to specific cells as it mentions in the [Keyboard Navigation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) section of the Ag-Grid docs under Custom Actions:

> **Custom Actions**
>
> Custom cell renderers can listen to key presses on the focused div.
>   The grid element that receives the focus is provided to the cell
>   renderers via the eGridCell parameter. You can add your own listeners
>   to this cell. Via this method you can listen to any key press and do
>   your own action on the cell eg hitting 'x' may execute a command in
>   your application for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I initially wrote this code for navigating `home/end` with `command+arrow key`, but have put comments where logic differs since 98% will be the same. Comments are untested but should work

I will divide this into 4 parts:

1. suppress the event so ag-grid does nothing by default
2. find a way for us to place a event listener on the right keys
3. compute which cell should be navigated to next
4. tell ag grid which cell should be selected

For #1, we can use `suppressKeyboardEvent` and either set it on `defaultColDef`(in `GridOptions´) or on every col def.

Mine looks like this:

```
const suppressKeyboardEventFn: ColDef["suppressKeyboardEvent"] = (
  params: SuppressKeyboardEventParams
) => {
  const key = params.event.key;
  const isControl = isControlKey(params.event);

  // For end/home, test for key === "Home" || key === "End" instead
  const isNavigation =
    key === "ArrowUp" ||
    key === "ArrowDown" ||
    key === "ArrowRight" ||
    key === "ArrowLeft";
  if (isNavigation && isControl) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

`isControlKey` is so it works on both mac&windows, and is written as recommended by MDN (not relevant if using home/end key):

```
const isMac = navigator.platform.startsWith("Mac");

export const isControlKey = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
  return isMac ? event.metaKey : event.ctrlKey;
};
```

For #2 where we want to handle the event ourselves, we can use `onCellKeyDown`:

```
const onCellKeyDownFn: GridOptions["onCellKeyDown"] = (cellKeyDown) => {
    if (cellKeyDown.event == null) {
      return;
    }

    const event = cellKeyDown.event as KeyboardEvent;
    const key = event.key;
    const isControl = isControlKey(event);

    // Instead write cases here for case "Home": and case "End":  
    switch (key) {
      case "ArrowUp": {
        if (isControl) {
          dispatch(navigateCell({ direction: "up", end: true }));
        }

        break;
      }
      case "ArrowDown": {
        if (isControl) {
          dispatch(navigateCell({ direction: "down", end: true }));
        }

        break;
      }
      case "ArrowRight": {
        if (isControl) {
          dispatch(navigateCell({ direction: "right", end: true }));
        }

        break;
      }
      case "ArrowLeft": {
        if (isControl) {
          dispatch(navigateCell({ direction: "left", end: true }));
        }

        break;
      }
    }
  };
```

Using the same `isControlKey` function. I have implemented redux navigation actions that handles navigating to home and end.

For #3, we can implement this in different ways. Here is how I FIND the correct cell to navigate to. Either one step to a direction, or to the end/home (which is our scenario, since I pass `end: true`)

```
// For using Home/End, add a case for each and mix logic from 
// below to find the correct cell. Last column logic is in 
// right when end===true and last row is in down when end===true etc

switch (params.direction) {
      case "up": {
        let newRowIndex;
        if (params.end === true) {
          newRowIndex = 0;
        } else {
          newRowIndex = selectedCell.lastKnownRowIndex - 1;
          if (newRowIndex < 0) {
            return;
          }
        }

        const node = gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(newRowIndex);
        if (node?.id == null) {
          log.warn("Could not find Node ID");
          return;
        }

        dispatch(
          selectCell({
            nodeId: node.id,
            colKey: selectedCell.colKey,
          })
        );
        break;
      }
      case "down": {
        let newRowIndex;
        if (params.end === true) {
          newRowIndex = maxRowIndex;
        } else {
          newRowIndex = selectedCell.lastKnownRowIndex + 1;
          if (newRowIndex > maxRowIndex) {
            return;
          }
        }

        const node = gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(newRowIndex);
        if (node?.id == null) {
          log.warn("Could not find Node ID");
          return;
        }

        dispatch(
          selectCell({
            nodeId: node.id,
            colKey: selectedCell.colKey,
          })
        );
        break;
      }
      case "right": {
        let nextColumn;
        if (params.end === true) {
          const columns = columnApi.getAllGridColumns();
          nextColumn = columns[columns.length - 1];
        } else {
          const column = columnApi.getColumn(selectedCell.colKey);
          if (column == null) {
            log.warn("Could not find column");
            return;
          }

          nextColumn = columnApi.getDisplayedColAfter(column);
        }

        if (nextColumn == null) {
          return;
        }

        dispatch(
          selectCell({
            nodeId: selectedCell.nodeId,
            colKey: nextColumn.getColId(),
          })
        );
        break;
      }
      case "left": {
        let nextColumn;
        if (params.end === true) {
          const columns = columnApi.getAllGridColumns();
          nextColumn = columns[1];
        } else {
          const column = columnApi.getColumn(selectedCell.colKey);
          if (column == null) {
            log.warn("Could not find column");
            return;
          }

          nextColumn = columnApi.getDisplayedColBefore(column);
        }

        if (nextColumn == null) {
          return;
        }

        dispatch(
          selectCell({
            nodeId: selectedCell.nodeId,
            colKey: nextColumn.getColId(),
          })
        );
        break;
      }
      default: {
        assertNever(params.direction);
      }
    }
```

Lastly #4, here is parts of my `selectCell` implementation that can give you some idea of how to make sure ag-grid focuses the right cell.

This code will focus the cell, add a range highlight, add a row selection, and make sure that it is visible if the viewport needs to jump:

```
    // no difference in logic when using Home/End!
    // just make sure correct cell is passed
    gridApi.ensureNodeVisible(node);
    gridApi.ensureColumnVisible(params.colKey);

    gridApi.clearRangeSelection();
    gridApi.addCellRange({
      rowStartIndex: rowIndex,
      rowEndIndex: rowIndex,
      columns: [params.colKey],
    });

    gridApi.setFocusedCell(rowIndex, params.colKey);
    node.setSelected(true, true)
```